# Combining elimination matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to combine several elimination steps into one matrix: more specifically I try to come up with a 3 by 3 matrix that first subtracts row 1 from row 2, subtract row 1 from row 3 and then subtract row 2 from row 3.

Its quite easy to get the first two steps simulated in a single matrix, but I am lost on how I get the last step - how do I get the new values from row 2 and subtract it to row 3?

Comment: Hi! For future reference, English already has a singular form for "matrices," namely *matrix.* The -ix form is [far more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=matrice%2C+matrix&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), so it might be worth switching. Continued use of this form may lead you to sillier mistakes like "vertice".

Comment: It's also a little amusing that you greeted us with "Hell guys," :)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments :) Do you also have an answer to my question :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do everything at once, and you don't realize that each operation corresponds to a single matrix. To perform row operations, we just need to multiply by a sequence of three simple $3\times 3$ matrices on the left of your matrix (say $X$).

Your first step (subtracting row 1 from row 2) is described by this matrix:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

So, computing $AX$ achieves that instruction on the rows of $X$.

Your second step (subtracting row 1 from row 3):

$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

So, computing $BAX$ does the first two instructions on the rows of $X$.

And your third step will be to find the matrix $C$ which subtracts row 2 from row 3. (I think I should leave this one for you to work out.) In any case, $CBAX$ performs all three row operations on $X$.

Once you determine $C$, you will multiply the matrices in order: $CBA=D$. The resulting $D$ does all three row operations in the right sequence!

Comment: That was also what I did, somehow I must have done my multiplications in a wrong manner. Possibly I did ((A * B)*C), while I should do (C*B)*A... Thanks for the help anyway...